# Want SUMIFS to compare two columns row by row

Tags: excel-formula

I wasn't sure how to explain it in the title, but here's my problem:
I want to sum the values of every row in column A when, in the same row, the value in col B is equal to the value in col C. For example `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"="&C2)` seems to work, but I don't want to compare to any specific cell, but the C-cell on that specific row, where the potential A-value is.

Edit: I could of course make an additional column with "If B2=C2" and so on by dragging it down, but this is what I want to avoid.

I also need to know the number of rows that is included in the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((A:A)*((B:B)=(C:C)))
```

But you should limit the full ranges to where ever your data ends, e.g.

```
= SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100)*((B1:B100)=(C1:C100)))
```

Comment: With limited ranges that seems to work! Without limits I got #VALUE! indication. I expect this sheet to soon be around 60 000 rows (and counting), but with a six figure limit I'll manage! But, now I have a new problem that I for some reason didn't predict. I need to know the number of rows that satisfies the condition. Maybe I should post a new question for that?

Comment: @Hias You can use `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT` with `COUNTA` to create a range that resizes itself.

Comment: @Hias If this answer works, please mark the answer as correct. I'm guessing the reason for the error is because perhaps something in the `A` column is not a number, (e.g. maybe `A1` contains a header title) which cannot be multiplied, hence the error.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Yes it works fine for what I initially asked for! Thanks! And, yes, A1 is a header, so I'll go with the limited number of rows. Unfortunately, I can't use the SUMPRODUCT because I also need the number of values added to that sum, and I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to limit the ranges but this `array formula` works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A,IF(B:B=C2,B:B))
```

This must be applied with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But now that I read your question again it seems that you just need:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,C2)
```

Comment: No, C2 was just an example. That's the first value in col C, and now I have to make an extra column, say col D, where in D2 I have the formula `=IF(B2=C2;"match";"")`, and then I pull this down till row 21565 or whatever, to replicate the formula on every row, but with relative references of course. Then I can have the condition $D:$D;"match" in a AVERAGEIFS or SUMIFS. A very cumbersome way when working with tens of thousands of rows, especially if I want to try out different IF's in col D. I don't get why in the `=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,"="&C2)` the &C2 part just can't be exchanged for C:C or similar